# Can I open the serial port 500k baudrated in a hardware-independent way using c #?

Tags: c#, serial-port, baud-rate

For a custom project I need to read the 500k baudrate serial port over rs422 using the c # serial port. My computer has the fintek rs422 / rs485 serial port (F81865). And can support up to 1497600m baudrate.
As far as I'm looking on the Internet, they did this by changing the clock speed of the serial port. Is this possible in windows or is there another way to programmatically open the serial port with 500k baudrate using c #?

My device manager ;
Here's [a link](https://i.hizliresim.com/7ByBd5.png)

Answer (score 1):

When using the [SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport) class, you can set the [BaudRate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.baudrate) by using a simple integer value:

```
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
// ... don't forget to set ALL other properties too!

mySerialPort.Open();
```

And the remarks section states:

> > The baud rate must be supported by the user's serial driver. The default value is 9600 bits per second (bps).

So if your driver supports that value, it should work.